Merlin Titanium vs. Cannondale CAAD 8
Looking for opinions about what to ride in RAGBRAI this summer.
I have a Cannondale CAAD 8 with Ultegra components 2x10 speed. This has been serving me well in very flat Florida where I live. No complaints.
I have a lead on a Merlin Titanium 3-25. Single Dura Ace crank with 38 teeth, with 11 speed SRAM Rival cassette. $1200 strikes me as good deal. Am I mistaken?
For the long ride this summer, will I have enough gear range to do the hills in southern Iowa without moving to a double crank?
Long term, does it seem like too good a deal to pass up? I can always change out components if I want to use a double crank.
Michael

Hi Michael, welcome to Bicycles SE. Your question involves recommendations which is out of scope for the site. Have a read of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour for an introduction.

While we can't make shopping recommendations per the FAQ, there are some things you could consider.
The Merlin (unknown model) has a DIY 1x drivetrain. At minimum, I'd want a narrow-wide chainring if I were using it. Otherwise, there are niches where 1x makes a lot of sense (cyclocross racing, many time trials), but a 1x11 is a bit limiting for general road use, a 38t ring is pretty small, and we don't know the rear gearing. Thus, we can't say if it will be enough for the hills; it might limit you on the way down them, however.
In general, rim brake bikes are getting phased out. Eventually, it may become harder to find replacement groupsets, although I assume that niche manufacturers will keep making wheels. Anyway, most newer groupsets only cater to hydraulic disc brakes, thus limiting you a bit. Modern bikes have much wider tire clearances, and wider tires are more comfortable than the narrower ones on bikes of that vintage.
The heart wants what it wants, but I don't see a strong logical case to upgrade to the Merlin.
